# gnome-settings-daemon thinks I have multiple monitors attached

Tags: gnome3, suspend, laptop

My laptop is not suspending when I close it, but `systemctl suspend` works perfectly, my suspend key (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>) works perfectly, suspend from the GUI works perfectly, `/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state` shows that my lid switch works perfectly, and my system is configured properly. Basically, everything seems to suggest that my laptop will suspend when I close it, except it doesn't.

After much research, I found out that something might be inhibiting the lid switch, and when I checked, I found the problem: `gnome-settings-daemon` was blocking `handle-lid-switch` because multiple displays are attached. However, only one display is attached, and that is the laptop's built-in display. My output from `xrandr` is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     59.99*+  40.03  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I am not sure why 5 displayports are listed. My laptop has only one displayport.  (It is a dualmode displayport, and I believe it also uses displayport for the screen internally.) The specifications listed for DP-3 match my built-in screen.  (I even used Pythagorean Theorum to verify the physical size.)  I am not sure what "Screen 0" is.

Why is `gnome-settings-daemon` doing this to me, and how can I fix it?

I am using Debian 9.1 with Gnome 3.22.2.